# nested select queries issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I have a select query that fetches me a table with rows, I want to get a particular row from this result but using the same first query, I explain:

We have a query:

```
$myQuery=("select col1,col2 from table where ..");
```

The seems is like that:

```
|col1|col2 |
|----------|
|res1|res11|
|res2|res21|
|res3|res31|
```

I want now to get `res31`, for example, but using the same last query called `$myQuery`, like we add a `select * from ...` to it.

I hope I did explain it, please say if I didn't enough.

Regards!

Comment: I might be just slow. What would be the expected result then?

Comment: How are you fetching the query? What are the fieldnames?  If it's the third result row your are after then it'll be `[2]` on the resultant array.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly: you can type just

```
SELECT * FROM ($myQuery) WHERE id=31 (OR any other stuff you wish to)
```

MySQL will understand that

Comment: you meant that "select * from (select * from ).." works fine??

Comment: @dany90 yup, you can do that. It's not the very fastest way, but it works

Comment: I'm using, Nafivat, I created a nested query, but the execution of it gives me this err:

Comment: @Corkscreewe, so how do you mean about SELECT * FROM ($myQuery)?! $myQuery is a PHP variable. please explain more a bit.

Comment: I was thinking of `$anotherQuery = "SELECT * FROM ($myQuery)"`. That, if it was a string variable in pure PHP. If you use some kind of framework or library (such as PDO), see its documentation about nested select queries. Please provide more information before asking more questions :)

Comment: @Corkscreewe, Ok, I used PHP, just tell me why it did not work? Here is my query, may helps: `$query = "select IDU from users where boss= '1' and IDP in(select IDP from projects where boss= '0' and IDU = 43)"`, I made another query: `$newQ = "select * from ($query)"`, I tried it by `$result = mysql_query($newQ); and then while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($result)){..}`, but as said, I gont an sql error, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), then you could use [binded params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to achieve this. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) would be even better to use.

Psuedo-code for how you would then do this with binded params:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT col1, col2, FROM table WHERE col2 = ?";
$result_31 = $db->select($myQuery, Array('res31')); 
$result_32 = $db->select($myQuery, Array('res32'));
```

This is just an example of binded your query param to the `?`. Dig into the APIs of mysqli and PDO for which suits you best. PDO is highly recommended though as you could later change from using mysql to postgres if needed, without changing all of your DB queries.